# how to split json data and set related data to their related html text by ajax

Tags: html, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am getting multiple fields data from linq query by json return in controller. Now, I want to set that multiple fields data to their related html text tools by ajax.

Here is my controller code,

```
public virtual IActionResult CustomerTotalUdharFine(int customerId)
{
    if (!_permissionService.Authorize(StandardPermissionProvider.ManageCustomers))
        return AccessDeniedDataTablesJson();

    var totalKhata = (from khata in _khataBookGroupRepository.Table
                           where khata.CustomerId == customerId
                           group khata by 0 into g
                           select new
                           {
                               TotalUdhariFine = g.Sum(x => x.UdharFine),
                               TotalJamaFine = g.Sum(x => x.JamaFine),
                               TotalUdhariRs = g.Sum(x => x.UdharRs),
                               TotalJamaRs = g.Sum(x => x.JamaRs)
                           });
    return Json(totalKhata);
}
```

Here is my ajax code,

```
$.ajax({
     url: "@(Url.Action("CustomerTotalUdharFine", "Customer"))",
     data: postData,
     success: function (data) {
         alert(JSON.stringify(data));
         if (data) {
             $("#TotalUdharFine").val(data.TotalUdhariFine);
             $("#TotalJamaFine").val(data.TotalJamaFine);
             $("#TotalUdhariRs").val(data.TotalUdhariRs);
             $("#TotalJamaRs").val(data.TotalJamaRs);
        }
    }
});
```

Now, in alert showing data in a comma format. For more clear lets see the image

[image]

Now, I want to split that data and set in the html text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
$("#TotalUdharFine").val(data[0].TotalUdhariFine);
$("#TotalJamaFine").val(data[0].TotalJamaFine);
$("#TotalUdhariRs").val(data[0].TotalUdhariRs);
$("#TotalJamaRs").val(data[0].TotalJamaRs);
```